# Multiple Line Ellipsis (clamp) through multi level html tags, which also works on IE, Firefox etc

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

After hours of research, i finally found a functioning way for having multiple Line Ellipsis (with JS, with plain CSS is not possible). 100 different Google results and Q/As, but currently this is the only one which works (only cause this one works not just on Chrome, but also on IE 11, Firefox etc.):

http://jsfiddle.net/Warspawn/9nz3T/

In my case, the problem in this fiddle is, it assumes that the text which is clamped, is inside a one single html tag (text-clamp ist the angular directive which does the job):

```
 <p text-clamp="1">a normally very long text</p>
```

In my case, the text i want to clamp is a h1 and it consists of multiple elements:

```
<h1 text-clamp="1">{{getIntroText()}}
      <span>&nbsp;as&nbsp;
         <span class="highlight">{{getCount()}}</span>
      </span>
      <span>&nbsp;in&nbsp;
          <span class="highlight">{{getAnotherPart()}}</span>
      </span>
</h1>
```

How can i get the above angular Directive working with my html?

This is my 2. fiddle with my h1 tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/9nqyLxuf/1/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there any reason for using angularjs `1.1.1`?... We're talking about a **2012 release**.

Comment: no.. it was just the version used in the 1. fiddle..  but angularJS is still a must (unfortunately)

Answer (score -1):

Just use the HTML `title` tag to display text on hover, and [AngularJS limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) directive will do the trick

```
<h1 title="{{foo}}"> {{introText | limitTo:9}} as <span>{{text | limitTo:5}}</span> in {{text2 | limitTo:1}}...
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/236sbL1u/2/)

Comment: i dont want to limit the text with a length, but with a max-line-count (text-clamp="1" above).. so it is not that easy.. the text also depends on your current browser window's width etc..